# Doexpresscheckoutpayment Payment has not been authorized by the user

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I'm getting below error when I access Doexpresscheckoutpayment service.

Error : Payment has not been authorized by the user
Error code : 10485

Please help me i am not able to figure out whats going wrong.

Below are the steps i followed:

1) Did setExpressCheckout got token
2) Using above token invoked getExpressChecoutDetails & got payerID 
3) Using above details i invoked Doexpresscheckoutpayment & got payment not authorize.

Version :98.0
Endpoint: https://api-aa.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution .. customer need to authorize payment...

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=

Answer (score 0):

You did not redirect the payer to PayPal!
Thus the "user did not authorize the payment" as stated in the error message.

The sequence must be ...

1. token = SetExpressCheckout()
2. redirect_to_paypal (token) -> paypal redirects to RETURNURL
3. RETURNURL: invoke GetExpressCheckoutDetails
4. DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Comment: How do you perform a payment without the user approval? (if I want to perform automatic payments using only my paypal id )